Can We Enter Temples While Holding Ashes for Immersion?
My father passed away a couple of weeks ago, and we are planning to go to Varanasi for the asthi visarjan. He had always wanted to visit Varanasi, and he also wished to see Ayodhya. So, would it be appropriate to take his ashes to the Ram Mandir in Ayodhya and a few other temples, like the Guruvayoor Shree Krishna Temple, to honor his wishes and his soul?
